# How do you sort data in a tableView alphabetically by section using Core Data?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3, tableview

I´m new to coding in Swift 3. 
I am trying to "replicate" the phone app from iPhone but I have some problems when displaying data in cells, they don´t appear (when apparently there´s some data in there, recovered from the Core Data class). 
The Core Data class consists of a Contact with some attributes like "firstName", "lastName", "phoneNumber", etc. I made it in the X.xcdatamodeld. Those attributes
are set in another VC and saved in there.
What I want to display in the cells is the firstName of each contact sorted alphabetically in sections, like the phone app.
Here is what I have so far.

```
extension Contact {
var titleFirstLetter: String {
    return String(firstName![firstName!.startIndex]).uppercased()
 }
}

class MainTableViewController: UITableViewController {
var listOfContacts = [Contact]() 
var sortedFirstLetters: [String] = []
var sections: [[Contact]] = [[]]

struct Storyboard {
    static let cellIdentifier = "Cell"
    static let showDetailIdentifier = "showDetail"
    static let showInformationIdentifier = "showInformationVC"
}

 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self

    let firstLetters = listOfContacts.map { $0.titleFirstLetter }

    let uniqueFirstLetters = Array(Set(firstLetters))

    sortedFirstLetters = uniqueFirstLetters.sorted()
    sections = sortedFirstLetters.map { firstLetter in
        return listOfContacts.filter { $0.titleFirstLetter == firstLetter }.sorted { $0.firstName! < $1.firstName! }
    }
 }

 override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    getData()
    tableView.reloadData()
 }

 func getData() {
    // 1. Create context
    let context = CoreDataController.persistentContainer.viewContext

    // 2. RecoverData from Database with fetchRequest
    do {
        try listOfContacts = context.fetch(Contact.fetchRequest())
    } catch {
        print("Error \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}

// MARK: - Tableview data source

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
     return sections.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return sections[section].count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let contact = sections[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: Storyboard.cellIdentifier, for: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = contact.firstName

    return cell
}

 override func sectionIndexTitles(for tableView: UITableView) -> [String]? {
    return sortedFirstLetters
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
   return sortedFirstLetters[section]
}
```

NOTE: CoreDataController is a class I made to be comfortable when managing the retrieving and saving into CoreData (what I did was to copy the generated code of CoreData from the AppDelegate.swift)
Hopefully you can help me to figure out why it doesn't work. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you using Sort Descriptor? it will resolve this issue

Comment: @UsamaSadiq where should I do that? In which method? Sorry for the obvious question but I´m new to Swift

Comment: Right after fetching request

Comment: @UsamaSadiq Do you mind doing that for me? I´m quite confused, the whole method if it´s possible... Thank you, Usama.

Comment: Check the answer you should change your getData function like this

Comment: Manuel let me know if you still face any issue

Answer (score 0):

> Should use NSSortDescriptor with your fetched query like:

```
  let sectionSortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "first_name", ascending: true)
  let sortDescriptors = [sectionSortDescriptor]
 fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = sortDescriptors
 let fetchedPerson = try context.fetch(fetchRequest) as! [Contact]
```

It may solved your problem. let me know if you getting issue after this.

Comment: Where should I do that? In which method? I´m quite confused @RajJoshi

Comment: @Manuel, please check this core data simple implementation code it may be solved your problem  https://github.com/rajkumar24u/CoreDataOperations

Answer (score 0):

Change your function like this

```
func getData() {
    // 1. Create context
    let context = CoreDataController.persistentContainer.viewContext

    // 2. RecoverData from Database with fetchRequest
    do {
        let fetchRequest = Contact.fetchRequest()
        let sectionSortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "first_name", ascending: true)
        let sortDescriptors = [sectionSortDescriptor]
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = sortDescriptors
        let fetchedPerson = try context.fetch(fetchRequest) as! [Contact]
        try listOfContacts = context.fetch(fetchRequest)
    } catch {
        print("Error \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}
```

Comment: I still having the same issue: contact is recognised (I print listOfContacts.count and it says the number that were before in the CoreData). The problem is that when I run the app, the tableview doesn´t show the firstName of the contact, despite there are some added in there. Moreover, I would like to sort them in sections, in a way that those whose first letter of the name is the same, are in the same section of the table view and I don´t know how to do that (hope that you can understand me). @UsamaSadiq

Comment: For sections you will have to use nafetchresultcontroller. I will send you once on my Mac .

Comment: You can check nsfetch controller

Comment: Whenever you can @UsamaSadiq. This problem is giving me some headaches... I have tried almost everything but I can´t figure the solution by myself. Thank you, once again, Usama

Comment: I can send you the project so you can try to see what´s wrong.